# Creating a table in MYSQL workbench

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

There's a Table Sales with one of the col name Ship Date.

WHY

**CREATE TABLE sales_2015 AS
SELECT * FROM Sales
WHERE 'Ship Date' BETWEEN '1-1-2015' AND '31-12-2015';**

is executing but not returning anything ?
No error but just not returning any values.
Any insights?

I dont Know what else to try as syntax is correct ?
But where is the error?

Comment: As well as needing to use the correct character to quote strings and identifiers, your `Ship Date` column should be a `DATE` column in `YYYY-MM-DD` format - ``WHERE `Ship Date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31';``